# Passing string as a case condition

Tags: c, switch-statement

In C language, is it possible to pass string as a case condition in switch case?
If possible, can AI (Artificial Intelligence) be achieved?

Comment: Which language are you using? What do you mean by Artificial Intelligence?

Comment: I am using C. Responding to the user by the phrases which they provide as input.  **Artificial Intelligence** can be shortly termed as decision taken by the computer itself.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass string as a case condition in switch case?

No - the `switch` statement only operates on integer values; `case` labels *must* be constant integral expressions.  You'd have to map the string onto an integer value, either by using a hash function or a lookup table or something.

```
#define MAX_LEN 80 // or however long you need
#define HELLO_STRING some-integer-value
#define GOODBYE_STRING some-other-integer-value
#define NO_MAPPING 0

int mapToInteger( const char * str )
{
  int mapValue = NO_MAPPING;

  /**
   * logic to map string to integer
   */
  return mapValue;
}

int main( void )
{
  char inputString[MAX_LEN];
  ...
  while ( fgets( inputString, sizeof inputString, stdin ) )
  {
    switch( mapToInteger( inputString ) ) 
    {
      case HELLO_STRING: 
        process_hello();
        break;

      case GOODBYE_STRING:
        process_goodbye();
        break;

      default:
      case NO_MAPPING:
        i_dont_understand();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Will case or whitespace matter?  In other words, should `"THIS IS A TEST"` and `"This is a test"` and `"tHiS     iS a     TeSt"` all give the same result?  If so, then your `mapToInteger` function (or whatever you decide to call it) will have to take all that into account.

> If possible, can AI (Artificial Intelligence) be achieved?

This is the programming equivalent of asking, "if I can use a hammer to nail two pieces of wood together, can I build an apartment complex?"  Yeah, sure, but you need to do a bunch of other stuff as well.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that a switch in C only accepts integer values, or something easy to cast to an integer (like a character).

There are workarounds tough, like using a hash function or using a series of “if”.

Concerning Artificial Intelligence, this is a vast field, that cannot be addressed with a simple switch. At least for a good result. You can have a look at [expert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) as a start.

Comment: If so then how could I achieve the task of accepting string as input and giving output based on the inputs. in other words which language will satisfy my requirement ?

Comment: It depends on what you would like to do with the strings. Do you expect precise strings? keywords? do you care about syntax? Do you want to interpret the meaning? There are many levels of complexity depending on what you would like to do. It is very difficult to answer without more details.